# Launch a process that terminates if the parent is killed in Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, process

Is it possible to launch a separate process, that automatically "dies" even if the script itself quits unexpectedly?

I am not quite familiar with process management and currently using the following to launch some third party software in background.

```py
def launch_stuff(stuff_path):
    info = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    info.dwFlags = subprocess.STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW #| subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS #| subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP
    info.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE

    process = subprocess.Popen(stuff_path, startupinfo=info,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

    return process
```

Yes, I can terminate that stuff if everything is okay, but can I somehow launch the stuff so it would "die" if the parent script is terminated unexpectedly. Like cmd window closed with the "X" button?

Comment: for this you need create job object and set here `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE`. and assign new created process to this job object. when your process exit all handles, including your job handle will be closed (if nobody duplicate it to another process) and child died when (last) job handle close. on *c++* this easy to write. on *pyton* - dont know